# Swift 2.0 array initialization

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a class (NavBar) with a couple variables that I want to place in an array.  I am currently getting this error.

> 'Instance member buttonOne cannot be used on type NavBar'

The code throwing the error is as follows.

```
// Buttons
var buttonOne: Button?
var buttonTwo: Button?
var buttonThree: Button?
var buttonFour: Button?
var buttonFive: Button?
var buttonsArray: [Button] = [buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive]
```

Comment: do at least what Arsen recommended. However, the error you posted barely relates to the optionality of your Button instances.

Comment: Your code is missing some context for this error to make complete sense.

Comment: try to upload missing context of your code.

Comment: @Abhinav below provided enough of the answer. I had to initiate the array empty first then later within a function I add the values to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, error says it all, you cannot add instance variables into another instance variable (Array). What you are looking for is something like this:

```
class navBar {

var buttonOne: Button?
var buttonTwo: Button?
var buttonThree: Button?
var buttonFour: Button?
var buttonFive: Button?

    var buttonsArray : [Button?] = []

    func addValues() {
        buttonOne = Button()
        buttonTwo = Button()
        buttonThree = Button()
        buttonFour = Button()
        buttonFive = Button()

        buttonsArray = [buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer which correctly address (and explains) the actual error being asked about in the question.

Comment: @Abhinav I would really appreciate you marking this question as a good question if you feel that way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store optional values in array of values. Use `[Button?]` instead of `[Button]`

```
var buttonsArray: [Button?] = [buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive]
```

Comment: Assuming the variables in the question are all instance variables of a class, this will produce the same error.  You're only solving a problem that's not being asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your base class is but you should get the idea. The following setup works:

```
class Button {}

class MyClass {

    var buttonOne: Button?
    var buttonTwo: Button?
    var buttonThree: Button?
    var buttonFour: Button?
    var buttonFive: Button?
    var buttonsArray: [Button?]

    init() {
        buttonsArray = [buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive]
    }
}
```

Ad Arsen pointed out, the array should be of `[Button?]` type to handle optionals and the array itself should be constructed in your `init` method. Depending on your base class this can be `initWithCoder:` or some other initialiser.